# select unique rows based on column by least group count

Tags: sql, sqlite, knex.js

I need to build a SQL query to select unique records from below table by least number of category count.

eg : simon is falling in to both Red and Green Category but  red is having only one record since i should give preference to red.

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Simon | Green |
| Simon | red |
| James | Green |
| Mathew | Green |

**Output should be**

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Simon | red |
| James | Green |
| Mathew | Green |

What would be the required SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using analytic functions make this problem tractable:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category) cat_cnt
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY cat_cnt) rn
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT Name, Category
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo

The first CTE finds the color count across the entire table for each color (regardless of name).  The second CTE restricts to the first record per name having the lower color count.

Regarding your using Knex, we *could* try to rewrite the above without using analytic functions, but it would be very ugly.  I might actually suggest just a raw query here.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if that helps. Please change the tablename accordingly.

declare @Category Table ( name varchar(100), category varchar(50))
insert @Category
select 'Simon','Green' union all 
select 'Simon','Red' union all 
select 'James','Green' union all 
--select 'James','red' union all 
select 'Mathew','Green'

;with CTE as 
(
select  [name],category, rank() over(partition by [name] order by best) ranking  from

( select [name],category,count(1) over( partition by category ) best   from @Category
) Temp 
)
select * from CTE where ranking=1